# Using Expect script to automate a win32 exe

Tags: windows, scripting, dos, expect

I'm trying to use Expect script on a Windows XP machine to automate a Command Line Menu based application. 
The application basically loads a menu saying 1.Perform option#1 2.Perform option#2 ... and waits for the user to key in the option, after which a further sub-menu is loaded. The following is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
  package require Expect
  puts stdout "Starting menu based CLI application"
  spawn C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\pds\CSERCLCD
  puts stdout "spawn completed"
  expect -re "*.*(Syntax is).*:.*" {
      puts stdout "received response from ping"
  }
```

The expect part of the code is never going into the condition specified above and the script just exits, is there anything wrong I am doing while calling the spawn on the application, please let me know.
The output is as follows:

```
 C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\Desktop>tclsh.exe test.tcl
 Starting menu based CLI application
```

Comment: Are not you getting the `spawn completed` in the console ?

Comment: @Dinesh its not printing that statement either, the output I have shown is all that is getting printed on the screen. thanks!